# Linear independence of the powers of a square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's consider the set of powers: $\text{\{}I, B, B^2, ..., B^n\text{\}}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. I know for sure that {$B^n = 0, \forall \, n\gt 3$}; so i remain with the set: {$I, B, B^2, B^3$}. Now (for further reasons) i would like to show that the latter set is linearly independent. I know some trivial counter-exmaples such as: {$B=0, B=I$}, but they are not good, since the case {$B=0$} is not interesting, and can't be {$B=I$}; infact, another hypothesis is that all eigenvalues of {$B$} are **not** equal to {$1$}. This should be enough to state {$B\neq I$}.

---

**NOTE)** the real problem here is to find $\text{\{}\alpha_{0}, \alpha_{1}, ..., \alpha_{n}\text{\}}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\left[A^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\alpha_{k}B^k\right]$, where {$B$} has the properties above, and  $\left[A=(I-B)\right]$. In this situation, is easy to find that: $$I=\alpha_0I+(\alpha_1 - \alpha_0)B+(\alpha_2 - \alpha_1) B^2+(\alpha_3 - \alpha_2) B^3 \\[3ex] (\alpha_0 - 1)I+(\alpha_1 - \alpha_0)B+(\alpha_2 - \alpha_1) B^2+(\alpha_3 - \alpha_2) B^3 = 0 $$ Now, if I equal the members of the first equation term-by-term (which is a reasonable shoot), i get the correct result; but what if i try to solve the second equation? I'll get the correct result if and only if i put all coefficient to zero.. but that's means the set {$I, B, B^2, B^3$} is linearly independent? I can't see that...

Comment: Hi! This question in general is answered by the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), which states that for any matrix $A$, there is a degree $n$ polynomial $f$ (closely related to the determinant) such that $f(A) = 0$, or if you want, $\{I, A, A^2, \cdots, A^{n - 1}, A\}$ are not linearly independent. I suppose the question is now how to use your condition that $A^4 = 0$, which is very strong.

Comment: Also a counterexample to your hypothesis about eigenvalues, try $B = \begin{pmatrix} -6 & -4 \\ 9 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $B^2 = 0$ and hence $B^4 = 0$. The eigenvalues of $B$ are both $0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Or more like they *know* that it is of degree $3$, and is wondering whether there's a way to find it without fully factoring the characteristics polynomial... I think.

Comment: Viewed the way they express their problem, they don't seem to be aware of these notions and the interplay between them, but let's wait and see what they answer after having looked at the last link if necessary. @GarethMa

Comment: @AnneBauval Hmm, he knows about eigenvalues so it's not that far away... not sure. Also, I didn't realise that the minimal polynomial of a nilpotent matrix is just $x^n$ (it definitely is obvious now :P), so I think your answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll assume $B^3\ne0$. Now suppose $rI+sB+tB^2+uB^3=0$. Multiplying by $B^3$, you get $rB^3=0$, so $r=0$, so $sB+tB^2+uB^3=0$. Multiplying by $B^2$ shows $s=0$, so $tB^2+uB^3=0$. Multiplying by $B$ shows $t=0$, so $uB^3=0$, so $u=0$, so your set is linearly independent.

Comment: That's a reasonable hint to say $B^3 \neq 0$ (and it is), but just to be clear, your answer holds only for $B \neq 0$ and $B \neq 1$?..

Comment: As $B^n=0$ for $n>3$, we certainly don't have $B=1$. And if $B^3=0$ (or if $B=0$) then it is trivial that $\{I,B,B^2,B^3\}$ is linearly dependent, since any set containing zero is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) of $B,$ and you want it to be of degree $4.$

You did not tell us everything you know about your matrix $B,$ only that it satisfies $B^4=0$ and $B\ne0.$ The minimal polynomial of $B$ is therefore $X^2$ or $X^3$ or $X^4,$ and all you have to do to prove that it is of degree $4$ is to prove that $B^3\ne0.$

Note that if $n$ is the size of your [nilpotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) $B$, its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) is $X^n,$ so (by [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)) $B^n=0.$ Hence for $B^3$ to be $\ne0,$ $n$ must be $\ge4.$

Comment: I'm not sure i understood your answer.. i know the CH theorem, but maybe in another way, since i use it to compute matrix functions. Anyway.. also i don't see how the minimal polynomial should be $X^n$.. i mean, shouldnìt it be $X$, with $X^n$ any multiple.. Moreover doesn' it means that every eigenvalues are zero..?

Comment: A nilpotent matrix $M$ satisfies $M^r=0$ for some $r>0$ (look at the link "nilpotent matrix"). Its minimal polynomial is then $X^r$ for the smallest such $r$ (look at the link "minimal polynomial"). Saying that the minimal polynomial is a power of $X$ is equivalent to: every eigenvalue is $0$ (hence also to: the *characteristic* polynomial is $X^n$).